# Wrap each char inside <i>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap each char from a given element inside a `<i></i>` tag.
I've tried two methods so far but each one has some issues.

#### First method:

I replace every char of the `.html()` of my element by its wrapped
version. The problem is that it also considers tags as chars and wraps them too.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    if ($(element).text() != '') { //Contains text
      var txt = $(element).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
      }).text();
      if (txt != '') { //Text outside span
        var chars = $(element).html().split('');
        var newChars = '';
        $.each(chars, function(i, el) {
          newChars += "<i>" + el + "</i>";
        });
        $(element).html(newChars);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  Lorem <span>teeest</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem aspernatur ducimus autem eveniet porro vitae ratione illum totam voluptatem alias. Impedit deserunt maiores excepturi ab repellendus atque aperiam quisquam iste! Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quasi mollitia perspiciatis explicabo, maxime quae</p>
```

#### Second method:

I tried a recursive approach which travels through my element's children and replace the text inside each one. The problem is, my output text somehow doubles and the children are misplaced in the result.

```js
function recursiveReplace(element) {
  if ($(element).children().length > 0) {
    $(element).children().each(function() {
      recursiveReplace($(this)[0]);
    });
  }
  var chars = $(element).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).text().split('');
  var newChars = '';
  $.each(chars, function(i, el) {
    newChars += "<i>" + el + "</i>";
  });
  console.log(newChars);
  $(element).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
  }).replaceWith(newChars);

}

$(function() {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    if ($(element).text() != '') { //Contains text
      var txt = $(element).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3;
      }).text();
      if (txt != '') { //Text outside span
        recursiveReplace(element);
      }
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem <span>teeest</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem aspernatur ducimus autem eveniet porro vitae ratione illum totam voluptatem alias. Impedit deserunt maiores excepturi ab repellendus atque aperiam quisquam iste! Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe quasi mollitia perspiciatis expli</p>
```

Would any of you have any idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: You can try the first option with `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: What's your aim? Is the meaning of the code to make the font-style italic? Because that can be done much easier :)

Comment: No I need to separate each char individually to be able to apply styles & classes to each char individually, I don't really care if it's a `i` tag.

Comment: I already tried with `.text()` but when you do `x.text(y)`, if `y` contains any HTML tag, it won't be interpreted as such. It will show up as text.

Comment: and what about `<span>teeest</span>`? you want to separate them also in single single character?

Comment: Yes, it should render it as : `<span><i>t</i><i>e</i><i>e</i><i>e</i><i>s</i><i>t</i></span>`

Comment: It would be on the whole document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recursive approach should work if you process each text node individually instead of concatenating it the way you do (as a result of running `text()` on the filtered collection)

```
function recursiveReplace(element){
  $(element).children().each(function() {
    recursiveReplace(this);
  });

  $(element).contents()
    .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType === 3; })
    .each(function(){
      var wrapped = '<i>' + this.textContent.split('').join('</i><i>') + '</i>';
      console.log(wrapped);
      $(this).replaceWith(wrapped);
    });
}
```

Notice how I also simplified your recursive call, there's no need to check if there are any children when using `each()` and there's no point in wrapping `this` just to immediately unwrap it.